# Service bus Send in a library ending

Tags: c#, debugging, azureservicebus

I am trying to extract the send method to a library. When I have this in a Console application it works fine. I move this to a class library and when I call the method, it exists at the CreateMessageBatchAsync method. What am I missing?
When debugging I am not able to get to the "var test" statement. the program exists with no exception

```
                var cln= new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
                var sender = cln.CreateSender(topicName);
                var body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
                var message = new ServiceBusMessage(body)
                {
                    ContentType = "application/json"
                };
                try
                {
                    var batch = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();

                    var test = "123";

                    if (!batch.TryAddMessage(message))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Error occured while sending object to topic");
                    }
                    await sender.SendMessagesAsync(batch);
                    await sender.DisposeAsync();
                    await cln.DisposeAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error sending message: {ex.Message}");
                    throw;
                }
```

Moved the same code to a .net 6 class library. When I call this library function from console app, the app exits and does not hit any break points (the test line) after this statement.

var batch = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();

```
    public async Task SendBatchMessageAsync(string connectionStr, string topic, ServiceBusMessage message, int maxRetries = 3)
    {
        int attempt = 0;
        do
        {
            try
            {

                var _client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
                var _sender = _client.CreateSender(topic);
                var serviceBusMessageBatch = await _sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
                if (!serviceBusMessageBatch.TryAddMessage(message))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error occured");
                }
                await _sender.SendMessagesAsync(serviceBusMessageBatch);
                await _sender.DisposeAsync();
                await _client.DisposeAsync();
            }
            catch (ServiceBusException ex) when (ex.Reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.MessagingEntityDisabled ||
            ex.Reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.MessagingEntityNotFound ||
            ex.Reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.ServiceTimeout ||
            ex.Reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.ServiceBusy)
            {

                _logger.Error($"Transient exception caught: {ex.Message}");
                attempt++;
                if (attempt >= maxRetries) throw; // Give up after maxRetries
                // Wait for a bit before retrying
                await Task.Delay(ComputeDelay(attempt));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Error sending message: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        } while (attempt < maxRetries);
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception you're getting?

Comment: @please, share the class library /code. I got that you are debugging and not able to get to the "var test" statement. the program exists with no exception

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the entire method/class that this code is in.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, what do you mean about " I move this to a class library and when I call the method, it exists at the CreateMessageBatchAsync method.", what is the 'it' in this place, send method?

Comment: @Srean No exception at all.